# Почему не правильно сортирует массивы(Bubble sort)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void bubbleSort(int* arr, char* arr2, char **arr3, int sizeArr) {
        int *temp;
    char *temp1;
    char *temp2;

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; ++i) {
            if ((arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) &&(arr2[i]>arr2[i+1] && (arr3[i]>arr3[i+1]))) {
                temp = &arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = *temp;

        temp1 = &arr2[i];
                arr2[i] = arr2[i + 1];
                arr2[i + 1] = *temp1;

        temp2 = arr3[i];
                arr3[i] = arr3[i + 1];
                arr3[i + 1] = temp2;

            }
        }
}

void func(int num, char **word, int *wc, char *is) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        wc[i]++;
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            if (i != j && strcmp(word[i], word[j]) == 0) {
                if (wc[i]++ == 1 && i < j)
                    is[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char** words = NULL; // указатель на слова
    int num_words = 0; // кол во слов
    char* delim = " \t\n,.!?:";
    int size_file = 0; //размер файла
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_file = ftell(fp); //находим размер файла
    printf("%d\n", size_file);
    char* buffer = calloc(size_file + 1, sizeof(char)); //буфер

    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Ошибка выделения памяти\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buffer, 1, size_file, fp);
    printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    char* istr = strtok(buffer, delim);
    while (istr) {
        words = realloc(words, (num_words + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        words[num_words++] = istr;
        istr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        //printf("%s\n", istr);
    }

    /*for (int i=0; i<num_words;i++) {
  printf("%p\n", words[i]);
  }*/
    printf("Количество символов в файле :%d\n", size_file);
    printf("Количество слов в файле :%d\n\n", num_words);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        puts(words[i]);
    }

    printf("\nНахождение одинаковых слов, не сортирован\n");
     int* wcnt = calloc(num_words, sizeof(int));
    char* is_first = calloc(num_words, sizeof(char));
    func(num_words, words, wcnt, is_first);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        if (wcnt[i] == 1 || is_first[i])
            if (wcnt[i] > 1 ) {
                printf("%s = %d\n", words[i], wcnt[i]);
            }
    }

printf("--------------\n");
bubbleSort(wcnt, is_first, words, num_words);
for (int i=num_words; i>0; i--)
 {
   if((wcnt[i]>1) && (is_first[i]>0))
   printf("%d %d %s\n", is_first[i], wcnt[i], words[i]);
 }

  fclose(fp);
  free(buffer);
  free(words);
  free(wcnt);
  free(is_first);
  return 0;
}
```

Вот код. Программа проходится по файлу, находит одинаковые слова и считает их частоту встречи. Если она больше 1, то выводит, но сначала выводит в не отсортированном виде. Попытался отсортировать с помощью пузырьковой сортировки, но она просто не сортирует, как был порядок слов таким и остался

Comment: В пузырьковой сортировке два вложенных цикла

Comment: Даже с двумя циклами не сортирует

Comment: Значит - неправильная реализация.  Больно сложное сравнение меня ещё смущает.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; ++i) { 
for (int j = (sizeArr - 1); j > i; j--) {
if (все таки с условием что именно должно быть я не понял) {
*остальное все так же*
}
}
}

Comment: Сам запутался с условием, не понимаю как должно быть

Comment: Реализацию пузырька найти нетрудно. А по сравнению - как догадаться, чего там в arr1,2,3 и посему они все одновременно должны быть больше соотв. следующих элементов?

Comment: Пузырьковую сортировку делал не раз, но именно просто с массивом чисел, с массивом чисел с слов впервые.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант сортировки массива строк с помощью функции `qsort()`:

```
//функция для сортировки строк по возрастанию
int comp (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return strcmp(*(char**)a,*(char**)b);
}
```

Функция `comp` отвечает за способ сортировки (по убыванию,по возрастанию и т.п.).

```
printf("--------------\n");
//bubbleSort(wcnt, is_first, words, num_words);
qsort (words, num_words, sizeof(char**), comp); //сортировка массива строк

//простой вывод слов
for(int i=0, repWord = 1; i< num_words; i++){
    //если слова одинаковые (и это не конец массива), то инкрементируем счётчик
    if((i!=num_words-1) && !strcmp(words[i], words[i+1])) ++repWord;    
    else{ //иначе выводим слово и кол-во его повторов
        printf("%d. %s - %d\n",(i+1),words[i], repWord);
        repWord = 1;}
}

/*
for (int i=num_words; i>0; i--)
 {
   if((wcnt[i]>1) && (is_first[i]>0))
   printf("%d %d %s\n", is_first[i], wcnt[i], words[i]);
 }
*/
```

Comment: Опять таки, тут простой вывод слов, а хотел, чтобы выводил сколько каждое слово встречается раз

Comment: @ЯрославЗахаров, поиск слов теперь происходит в выводе с помощью функции strcmp().

Comment: Cпасибо! А чем мой вариант сортировки пузырьком был плохим?

Comment: Скорее всего из-за того, что он был не рабочим. Вот [материал](https://learnc.info/algorithms/bubblesort.html) по сортировке.

Comment: Но получается можно и отсортировать с помощью пузырьковой сортировки, не только с помощью быстрой?

Comment: Так зачем изобретать велосипед, когда в библиотеках имеется алгоритм сортировки любых массивов qsort() ?

Comment: Эх, протестировал программу и заметил, что она выводит массив точно так же как и неотсортированный. То есть он выводи слова по мере их встречи, а я хотел остортировать, и чтобы выводил слова с самой большой частотой к самой малой. например: the=4; was=3, и т д

Comment: Вроде же спрашивали про пузырьковую сортировку - вы зачем qsort дали то?